# How do I Solve this problem in scyllaDB installation?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, scylla

I am following this steps for installation
https://www.scylladb.com/download/?platform=ubuntu-20.04&version=scylla-4.3#open-source

Version :- Ubuntu 20.04
Scylla 4.3

Once I reach on below step I get this error,

$ sudo apt-get install -y scylla

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
scylla-tools-core : Depends: python-yaml but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: It's not possible to determine the problem from the log you posted. Try following the recipe in https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear there is something broken or strange on your system setup, because the error indicates that the `python-yaml` can't be installed, but that's a valid package on Ubuntu 20.04 - see https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/amd64/python-yaml

Perhaps when you added Scylla's package source you accidentally broke the system's default package sources? Try to install the `python-yaml` package manually, and see what happens.

Finally, please note that Scylla 4.3 is already old - Scylla 4.4 is already out for months, and 4.5 is in the last release-candidate stages, and when it's officially released, support for 4.3 will stop (Scylla only supports two major open-source releases at a time). So you should consider whether you really want Scylla 4.3 or try a newer version.